# Scala API with encode special character not working for client

Tags: scala

We have this function which takes care of special character. For example this function will convert `He shouldn’t be allowed` to `He shouldn�t be allowed`.

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, 
io.circe.syntax._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.optics.JsonPath._

private def bytesToJsonCirce(value: Array[Byte]): Json = {
    parse(encodeCharacters(value.map(_.toChar).mkString)) match {
      case Right(x: Json) => x
      case Left(err: ParsingFailure) =>
        logger.error(err.getLocalizedMessage)
        Json.Null
    }
  }  

private def encodeCharacters(x: String): String = {
        val encodeChar = '�'
        (x.toCharArray map {
          case y if y.isControl => encodeChar
          case y => y
        }).mkString
      }
```

Now we are trying to consume this API response at client side(python) getting error
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)` . If we apply `.encode("utf8")` at client its giving back `He shouldn�t be allowed` but we are loosing the original form `He shouldn’t be allowed`.

Also this `UnicodeEncodeError` is not desired without `.encode("utf8")`. How it can be achieved at scala front .

Comment: I am a bit confused, what side is in Scala - server or client?

Comment: Server actually

Comment: Does you API produce JSON responses? Where does the `value: Array[Byte]` come from, which I understand is a JSON?

Comment: Yes its JSON response only

Comment: If `value: Array[Byte]` is a UTF-8 encoded string then treating each element of the array as separate character is wrong because some characters can take more than a byte.

Comment: `value: Array[Byte]` will come like this `Array(110, 117, 108, 108)` byte representation of each character of a string . We are mapping each  character to `string` and checking against each character of that string `isControl` or not .

Comment: `’` is not a control character so the example you give will be unchanged

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `\ufffd` is not a valid ASCII character:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd'

`\ufffd` is the Unicode value of `�` so the problem is that the replacement value `encodeChar` is not a valid ASCII value. Try changing `encodeChar` to a valid ASCII character.

Comment: I was more looking for instead of replacing by same encoder `�` , can I have some escape mechanism that can help to retain the actual value.